# Drupal White Screen of Death - No Errors with Errors turned ON

Tags: php, drupal, wsod

I have all errors turned on (error_reporting(-1)) in Drupal, but for some reason most errors do not come through in the logs or on screen. I can replicate the problem by simply changing a function name to something else, and I would expect to see a function doesn't exist error, but I just get a white screen. I have tried replicating this outside of the Drupal framework and I can't - so it leads me to believe it isn't my setup of PHP (Zend Server/Apache2/PHP/Windows) but is in Drupal somewhere...

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to enable/disable modules to see when I could see errors again and limited it to two modules that turned off the error handling... After more investigation I found that in a nusoap.php class error reporting had been turned off because certain errors kept showing (some other developer had turned it off)... Turned it back on, upgraded nusoap.php and now all is working... Thanks for the help all

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is enabled as well.

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );
```

Comment: I have this in index.php:

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

Comment: 200 - I have found the module group that is causing it, now just enabling/disabling all modules in that group to find the cause.

Answer (score 3):

I know this may be late, but it helped me. Most times a module causes WSOD, I couldn't just disable modules to test which it was, since I may have lost data in the process. What I did was to edit this function in module.inc

```
function module_invoke_all($hook) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $hook from the arguments.
  unset($args[0]);
  $return = array();
  foreach (module_implements($hook) as $module) {

        print "Starting loading $module <br />";

        $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
        if (function_exists($function)) {
          $result = call_user_func_array($function, $args);
          if (isset($result) && is_array($result)) {
            $return = array_merge_recursive($return, $result);
          }
          elseif (isset($result)) {
            $return[] = $result;
          }
        }

        print "Finished loading $module <br />";

  }

  return $return;
}
```

And I added those 2 print statements in the code above, then refresh the page, the module which didn't reach the "Finish loading $module" statement is the one with the problem... it was devel in my case.

After finding the module, you can go into the system table and look for that module, set it's status = 0 and bootstrap = 0 or run the query:

```
UPDATE system SET status = 0, bootstrap = 0 WHERE name = 'module_name' LIMIT 1
```

Reference: [Debugging Drupal White Screen of Death (WSOD)](http://gleamly.com/article/debugging-drupal-white-screen-death-wsod)

Comment: Good idea - it ended up being one module that was turning off error reporting and then erroring (so it stopped output stream). Took a while but I ended up fixing it :)

Comment: thanks to this answer i realized that in my case WSOD was caused by Devel module on Drupal 7 and Blue Host

Answer (score 2):

[Full documentation of WSOD](http://drupal.org/node/158043).

Answer (score 1):

this might be the dumbest answer on stackoverflow, but this happened to me when i was desiging a cakephp site from scratch and had white background and white font in the css, and couldn't get anything, no errors or sql dump.

see if you can select text on the screen.

Comment: haha cheers for the reply, but there is no source when I "View Source".... and nothing can be selected on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check php's setting for "error_reporting", maybe?  Mine's set to:

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: if you look above, it says that I set error_reporting to -1 (all errors)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I would get strange errors including WSOD if i included a file that had the closing  php token.

`?>`

It took me forever to track down.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking, though the system and modules are quite extensive so I was trying to use this as a last resort! :)

Answer (score 0):

I note your question has already been answered but it may be useful for others reading this to know that sometimes a WSOD can be caused by an older incompatible version of PHP on the server. Drupal 7 requires PHP 5.3 but many servers are still running PHP 5.2. This can cause a WSOD with no error messages.